# WM_GETICON for Metro app returns default icon handle

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, icons

I am trying to retrieve the icon handle for metro apps by sending a message with the WM_GETICON message to the window. I however keep getting the default icon handle (65575). Has something changed in Windows 8 with regards to the icons?

Comment: Are you sure you are sending the message to the correct window? It would help to see the code you are using to get the window handle and send the message, in case you're doing something else wrong.

Comment: Metro-style apps don't have icons.

Comment: @RaymondChen OK that explains it. I am curious; what image does the Windows task manager display for the Metro-style apps?

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield I double checked the process id from the window handle with the actual pid shown in task manager and they match. Like Raymond Chen said Metro-style apps not having icons seems to be the reason for this behavior.